# Android supprot HLS Adaptive Bitrate Streaming?

Tags: android, http-live-streaming

I trying to use HLS Adaptive Bitrate Streaming

I make variant playlist : 
File Name is test.m3u8

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1, BANDWIDTH=200000
low/low.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1, BANDWIDTH=311111
middle/middle.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1, BANDWIDTH=484444
high/high.m3u8
```

Each m3u8 file :

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:4
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXTINF:6.040000,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:158484@0
http://myserver/hls/Test/low/low.ts
#EXTINF:4.200000,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:121824@158484
http://myserver/hls/Test/low/low.ts
#EXTINF:10.000000,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:286512@280308
http://myserver/hls/Test/low/low.ts
..........
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

my folder structure :

```
/hls/Test/test.m3u8
/hls/Test/low/low.m3u8
/hls/Test/middle/middle.m3u8
/hls/Test/high/high.m3u8
```

My Problem is :

iOS Device calls this URL(`http://myserver/hls/Test/test.m3u8`)
video plays working.

Android Device calls this URL(`http://myserver/hls/Test/test.m3u8`)
video does not play.
But, I call url(`http://myserver/hls/Test/low/low.m3u8`)
video plays working.

Android Device : samsung galaxy note 3

Android Client source :

```
@Override   
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video);

    initUI();
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://myserver/hls/Test/test.m3u8");

    MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
    video_videoView.setMediaController(mc);

    video_videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
    video_videoView.start();
}   

private void initUI() { 
    video_videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_videoView);
}
```

Android LogCat Error :

```
12-19 11:20:12.547: I/MediaPlayer(1704): path is null   
12-19 11:20:12.567: D/MediaPlayer(1704): setDataSource IOException happend :    
12-19 11:20:12.567: D/MediaPlayer(1704): java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider:   http://myserver/hls/Test/test.m3u8
12-19 11:20:12.567: D/MediaPlayer(1704): at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1053)
12-19 11:20:12.567: D/MediaPlayer(1704): at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:907)
12-19 11:20:12.567: D/MediaPlayer(1704): at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:834)
12-19 11:20:12.567: D/MediaPlayer(1704): at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:978)
12-19 11:20:12.567: D/MediaPlayer(1704): at android.widget.VideoView.openVideo(VideoView.java:338)
12-19 11:20:12.567: D/MediaPlayer(1704): at android.widget.VideoView.access$2100(VideoView.java:71)
12-19 11:20:12.567: D/MediaPlayer(1704): at android.widget.VideoView$7.surfaceCreated(VideoView.java:618)
12-19 11:20:12.567: D/MediaPlayer(1704): at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:602)
12-19 11:20:12.567: D/MediaPlayer(1704): at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:94)
12-19 11:20:12.567: D/MediaPlayer(1704): at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:183)
12-19 11:20:12.567: D/MediaPlayer(1704): at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:888)
12-19 11:20:12.567: D/MediaPlayer(1704): at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2199)
12-19 11:20:12.567: D/MediaPlayer(1704): at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1254)
12-19 11:20:12.567: D/MediaPlayer(1704): at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6624)
12-19 11:20:12.567: D/MediaPlayer(1704): at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:812)
12-19 11:20:12.567: D/MediaPlayer(1704): at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:612)
12-19 11:20:12.567: D/MediaPlayer(1704): at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:582)
12-19 11:20:12.567: D/MediaPlayer(1704): at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:798)
12-19 11:20:12.567: D/MediaPlayer(1704): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
12-19 11:20:12.567: D/MediaPlayer(1704): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-19 11:20:12.567: D/MediaPlayer(1704): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
12-19 11:20:12.567: D/MediaPlayer(1704): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
12-19 11:20:12.567: D/MediaPlayer(1704): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-19 11:20:12.567: D/MediaPlayer(1704): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-19 11:20:12.567: D/MediaPlayer(1704): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
12-19 11:20:12.567: D/MediaPlayer(1704): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
12-19 11:20:12.567: D/MediaPlayer(1704): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-19 11:20:12.567: D/MediaPlayer(1704): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
```

Please help..

Comment: Can you provide information about which version of Android you are using?

Comment: I used the Android 4.4 version

Comment: it doesnt support directly. You need to make your own player to do so which is bit tricky. I have tried that earlier but was not able to get the same quality as on the IOS. It directly not able to parse and change the different m3u8 files generally.

Comment: This is not answer to your question but, when i was working with HLS on android few years ago, I've used Vitamio SDK https://www.vitamio.org/en/

Answer (score 1):

The native VideoView doesn't really support HLS streaming.
Build a custom video player using ExoPlayer

Mentioned in Android Developer Console:

"ExoPlayer supports features not currently provided by MediaPlayer, including Dynamic adaptive streaming over HTTP (DASH), SmoothStreaming and Common Encryption. It's designed to be easy to customize and extend, allowing many components to be replaced with custom implementations. Because ExoPlayer is a library that you include in your application, it can be easily updated along with your app"

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer.html

Also, you can search for libraries which are wrapper around ExoPlayer.

Ex. : https://github.com/brianwernick/ExoMedia

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12237118)

Comment: @Mohit Noted! I have edited the answer. Do review. Thanks.

Comment: I have `http  url`  `720p` video with the same `url` how can I achieve `streaming like youtube 144p 22op 720p`..please help